# Select rows that have at least one null value

Tags: mysql, sql, null, mariadb

I had a database that allowed `NULL` in many of its columns (in all tables). I would like to know if there is a clean way to select from a table all the rows that have at least one value set to null in any column.

I know that this can be achieved by using:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `column_1` is null OR `column_2` is null ... with all columns
```

but I want to know if there is a cleaner and more general way so I must not make a new query for every new table.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use `information_schema.COLUMNS` to generate (via `CONCAT`) `SELECT` statement(s) with all the columns for all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry But it cant be done a cleaner way

If you could select all the rows and then apply a function it could be made but it's just not the way SQL was built.

Answer (score 2):

What you "know" is wrong.  The correct logic would be:

```
where column_1 is null or column_2 is null or . . .
```

This is the correct syntax and a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: thanks for the correction, that's what i meant. I corrected my post. Though I want to know if there is a more general way that i can apply to many different tables with different column names

Comment: @Dknacht There's nothing that automatically loops over columns dynamically. You could write a stored procedure that gets the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and builds the SQL dynamically.